# Installed redoc-cli npm package but on trying to run it, it says command not found. macOS 10.15.4

Tags: macos, bash, zsh, npm

Here's what I have done. See the last line for the error:

```
cb-machan@cb-machan bin % npm i redoc-cli

> styled-components@4.4.1 postinstall /usr/local/bin/node_modules/styled-components
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js || exit 0

Use styled-components at work? Consider supporting our development efforts at https://opencollective.com/styled-components
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/bin/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/bin/package.json'
npm WARN bin No description
npm WARN bin No repository field.
npm WARN bin No README data
npm WARN bin No license field.

+ redoc-cli@0.9.7
added 309 packages from 211 contributors and audited 1381 packages in 37.029s

9 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
cb-machan@cb-machan bin % redoc-cli --help
zsh: command not found: redoc-cli
```

Looks like my PATH variable is set properly:

```
cb-machan@cb-machan bin % npm prefix
/usr/local/bin
cb-machan@cb-machan bin % echo $path
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /usr/local/mysql/bin /Users/cb-machan/apache-ant-1.10.7/bin
```

I tried switching my shell to bash but the error persists.

Comment: What does the "npm -v" return you?

Comment: @Didier `npm -v` returns `6.14.4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the trouble was that I **had not** installed `redoc-cli` **globally**.

The following steps fixed the issue:

1. Uninstall `redoc-cli` and `redoc`

```
npm uninstall redoc-cli -S
```

```
npm uninstall redoc -S
```

2. Install `redoc-cli` globally

```
npm install redoc-cli -g
```

Comment: Just faced this exact problem and really happy that you answered your own question! :)

Comment: work for me, thanks @John

Comment: Thank you, this helped me as well!